# Autosys Command List and Job Scheduling every half an hour

Tags: autosys

Where can I find all the command list for Autosys JIL. What is the official site where I can get the complete list of Autosys commands with examples ?

For example I want to run a shell script every half an hour everyday of the week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the start time as 0, 30 which means every 30 mins and days of week as all as you want the job to run everyday

```
/* ----------------- template ----------------- */

insert_job: template job_type: c 
box_name: box1
command: ls -l
machine: localhost
owner: lyota01@TANT-A01
permission: gx,ge,wx,we,mx,me
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: 0,30
```

Comment: this is not correct. The correct command is: start_mins

Answer (score 3):

Use **`start_mins`** to specify specific mins of an hour to run the job.

E.g.

```
insert_job: my-job-for-specific-mins
job_type: c
command: date
machine: my-host
permission: mx
n_retrys: 0
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_mins: "05,35"
description: "Test specific mins of hour"
std_out_file: /var/tmp/job-name.out
std_err_file: /var/tmp/job-name.out
alarm_if_fail: 1
timezone: London
```

The specified job will run at 5 mins and 35 mins past every hour.

Answer (score 1):

Link to the command line list for Autosys jil and other command functions
http://supportconnectw.ca.com/public/autosys/infodocs/autosys_cheatsheet.asp

For scheduling instructions and training classes, register with CA at support.ca.com and provide your site license info.

Comment: Broken link? Can anyone correct?